# preorders induced by continuous functions to the reals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, order-theory

Any function to a (total) order induces a (total) preorder on its domain.  What can be said about the total preorders induced by a continuous function from a "nice" topological space (for instance, a Euclidean space) to the reals?

Comment: What kind of things are you looking for to be said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to characterize all preorders induced by a real-valued function. The following result is essentially due to Debreu and builds on previous work by Cantor.

**Theorem:** Let $(T,\preceq)$ be a totally preordered set. The the following are equivalent:

1. There exists a function $u:T\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $u(x)\leq u(y)$ if and only if $x\preceq y$.
2. There exists a countable set $C\subseteq T$ such that for all $x\prec y$, there is $c\in C$ with $x\preceq c\preceq y$.

**Proof:**

(1$\implies$2)$~~~$ Let $u$ be such a function. Call an interval $(r,s)$ a *gap* if there exists $x,y\in T$ with $u(x)=r$, $u(y)=s$ and $u^{-1}\big((r,s)\big)=\emptyset$. Any two gaps are disjoint and contain a rational number. So there are only countably many gaps. Pic for each gap $(r,s)$ elements $x,y\in T$ with $u(x)=r$, $u(y)=s$ and collect these elements in the countable set $C_1$. For each open interval with rational endpoints $(p,q)$ such that $u^{-1}\big((p,q)\big)\neq\emptyset$, pick an element $x\in u^{-1}\big((p,q)\big)$ and collect them in the countable set $C_2$. Then $C=C_11\cup C_2$ has the desired properties.

(2$\implies$1)$~~~$ Let $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots\}$ be such a countable set. For $x\in T$, let $$L_x=\big\{n\in\mathbb{N}:c_n\prec x\big\}$$ and $$U_x=\big\{n\in\mathbb{N}:c_n\succ x\big\}.$$ By letting $$u(x)=\sum_{n\in L_x}\frac{1}{2^n}-\sum_{n\in U_x}\frac{1}{2^n}$$ for all $x\in T$, we get the desired function. $~~\blacksquare$

If $u$ is continuous, we get that the sets $\{y\in T:y\succ x\}$ and $\{y\in T:y\prec x\}$ are open for all $x\in T$. If $T$ is a second countable topological space with a complete preorder on it, this condition in sufficient for the preorder being induced by continuous real valued function. The proof, due to Debreu, is quite complicated, see [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2525513) (JSTOR). This settles of course the case in which $T$ is a Euclidean space. A book that contains a lot of material around these themes is "Representations of preferences orderings" by Bridges and Mehta.

Comment: Thanks!  This completely answers my main question and lets me know what field it is part of.